# What goes wrong with my code?

Tags: java, vert.x

Hi i am undeploying verticles which are deployed from a single verticle . I got there deployment id's in set of string and i am using this set in shutdown hook for undeploying these verticles. Here is my shutdown hook.  Fca is the verticle class which deploys other verticles.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                if(deploymentSet!=null){
                    for (String deployId : deploymentSet){
                        container.undeployVerticle(deployId);
                        logger.info("Undeployed verticle with Deployment id :"+deployId);
                    }
                }
                container.exit();
                Fca.this.stop();
                logger.info("All verticles are Shutdown.");
            }
        });
```

In logs i got message "Undeployed verticle with Deployment id :" three times for three verticles but then it throws error like "no verticle found with deployment id " Why is that ? I am trying too hard to get pass this error. Please help me.

Comment: Show us the `undeployVerticle`-function. EDIT: Nevermind; it's part of the [API](http://vertx.io/api/java/org/vertx/java/platform/Container.html#undeployVerticle%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: This piece of code i pasted is the shutdown hook which get activated when send SIGINT or kill -15 over the process its perfectly working fine but after undeployment logs i got error .

Comment: Maybe you should debug through this function to see the content of `deploymentSet`. Maybe it contains three `ids` and one `null` or empty value.

Comment: No , I have checked set contain only three values , and no null . i dont when it get reiterate through the set again so that it got that error.

Comment: Do you deploy the verticles back to the container before you reiterate through it? If you don't, then the container will be empty on your second iteration.